# Show #pragma message in header only once during build

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, pragma

I have a bunch of `#pragma message("A message")`s in a `config.h` header that gets included in many places in the project; the goal is to inform which configuration options are chosen during build. The header is protected by `#ifndef #define` style headerguards. The problem is that every time this header gets included, the message is printed. Is there a better way to do this so that the message gets printed only once during the build?

**Edit:** I understand that build options are usually manipulated and viewed with build tools such as cmake, qmake, autotools etc. but I don't really have a choice on the build tools due to the nature of the project.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with `#pragma message`

Comment: You need to be able to pass the information that a message has been printed between the different compilation units.  This seems unreasonably difficult.  I would rather write a script to filter out duplicates lines from the output.

Comment: @GillBates what can be another solution that allows printing configuration options during build?

Comment: So what *are* the build tools? For instance this is not very difficult with GNU make, or even if the build system is just a shell script. Perhaps refine your tags?

Comment: @MikeKinghan The build tools are proprietary from Microchip and are already quite broken and unstable. I would not dare isolate or cook up scripts for my own use that integrate their tools. I agree that maybe any (partial) answer to this particular problem would not be useful in general or even the situation is beyond any help since printing this type of message is not the compiler's job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the `#pragma message` in a separate file you only include once from `config.h`. gcc might print these pragmas even when inside a false conditional, but it won't include a file from inside a false conditional. So someting like this:

```
/* config.h */
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#ifndef CONFIG_MESSAGE_PRINTED
#define CONFIG_MESSAGE_PRINTED
#include "config_message.h"
#endif

/* ... */
#endif /* CONFIG_H */
```

In `config_message.h`:

```
#pragma message("A message")
```

Comment: Why would the `CONFIG_MESSAGE_PRINTED` include guard behave differently to the `CONFIG_H` one?

Comment: @KarstenKoop It doesn't, but `include` directives inside false conditionals are ignored.

Comment: I think his problem is not multiple inclusions from the same compilation unit, but different compilation units with the same include producing the same message. But as it is not completely clear from the question, he might also mean the same compilation unit, and your answer could be helpful in that case.

Comment: My answer makes sure that the file cobtaining the message pragma is only ever included once. This makes sure that it is printed only once.

Comment: @FUZxxl I think the problem is with multiple compilation units because this does not work, messages are still printed multiple times.

Comment: @AyberkÖzgür Yes, each compiler invocation prints the message once. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @fuz, maybe we can write `#pragma message` in a separate `.c` file.
Here is the example:

```
/* config.h */
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#define CONFIG_OPTION_A
#define CONFIG_OPTION_B

#endif /* CONFIG_H */
```

Write messages in a `.c` file:

```
/* config_msg.c */
#include "config.h"

#ifdef CONFIG_OPTION_A
#pragma message "Config option A is enabled!"
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_OPTION_C
#pragma message "Config option C is enabled!"
#endif
```

Finally add compilation dependency to the Makefile (that is, `config_msg.o`):

```
/* Makefile */
.PHONY: all
%.o: %.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $<
config_msg.o: config_msg.c config.h
    gcc -c -o $@ $<
all: main.o config_msg.o
    gcc -o main $^
```

As long as `config.h` is modified, the `config_msg.o` will be re-compiled and print the messages within it. (Adding `config.h` to the dependencies of `Rule config_msg.o` is necessary. And this also depends on higher priority of `Rule config_msg.o` than `Rule %.o`. Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Here is the test:

```
$ make all
gcc -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -c -o config_msg.o config_msg.c
config_msg.c:4:9: warning: Config option A is enabled! [-W#pragma-messages]
#pragma message "Config option A is enabled!"
        ^
1 warning generated.
gcc -o main main.o config_msg.o
$ make all
gcc -o main main.o config_msg.o
```

Run after adding `#define CONFIG_OPTION_C` to `config.h`:

```
$ make all
gcc -c -o config_msg.o config_msg.c
config_msg.c:4:9: warning: Config option A is enabled! [-W#pragma-messages]
#pragma message "Config option A is enabled!"
        ^
config_msg.c:8:9: warning: Config option C is enabled! [-W#pragma-messages]
#pragma message "Config option C is enabled!"
        ^
2 warnings generated.
gcc -o main main.o config_msg.o
```

I don't think this is a perfect solution. But hope it will help.
:)